# How to make a Grid view showing 4 columns in a row?

Tags: gridview, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react to create a Grid. The content of each Grid cell is from EventList component. There are multiple events. How can I make the grid to display 4 cells in one row in my case? Thanks!

```
return (
      <Grid columns='equal'>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
          <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
            <EventList
              loading={loading}
              moreEvents={moreEvents}
              events={loadedEvents}
              getNextEvents={this.getNextEvents}
            />
          </div>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
          <Loader active={loading} />
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
);
```

I've tried to wrap `<Grid.Row>` around `<Grid.Column>`, but it won't automatically put 4 cells in one row. It just put only one cell in the first 4 width, and each row only has one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Found react-stack-grid to achieve the same